# Register bot and deploy to Azure

Tags: azure, botframework

I created a bot using the bot framework and I've only been developing and testing it locally on my computer.

I now need to register the bot so I can use it online and integrate it with other MS services like Cortana.

But I can't find a way to do this, everything is so confusing and all tutorials seem to be outdated. For example most of them tell me to go to https://dev.botframework.com and click on "Register a bot", but that tab doesn't exist anymore and when I click "Create" I'm redirected to Azure where it seems like instead of registering a bot I'm creating a new one.

Can someone provide a step by step solution to register an existing bot (on my computer) on Azure?

Sorry of this isn't the kind of question intended for this site but I think more people might have the same question and this can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the Bot framework moved to General Availability from Preview, things have been moved to azure and you need to register/create the bot now from azure portal.
Since you have the bot code running locally, the steps to follow would be:

1. Create a new bot service in azure. Follow the steps detailed in [bot-service-quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). This will create a basic bot, with the template you chose (Would suggest to chose 'Basic' in Bot template option).
2. Next step is to move your local bot code to the newly created azure bot service. To do this there are couple of ways. Use [Online code editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-online-code-editor?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to make the necessary changes (In case there is very little change). The second option would be to use [Download Source code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-download-source-code?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) option in `Build` under the BOT MANAGEMENT section in azure bot service. The docs have detailed steps explaining this process and how to upload back the code to azure bot service. The third way is to use [Continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-continuous-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-3.0), this basically is setting up the code to be loaded to bot from source control tools like git, VSTS, bitbucket, etc. In this, the code is directly deployed to bot service (without you manually deploying) as per your continuous deployment settings.
3. Now that you have your bot code in azure bot service, next would be to enable channels like webchat, Cortana, etc. Follow [Channel registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) doc to see the process to deploy to each channel. The enabling and disabling of the channels can be controlled from the **'Channels'** blade in the azure portal.